# scroll smoothly to the specific position

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have a listview which contains large no of datas,but here the problem is, it is not scrolling to the top most.Listview is updating,and the listview size is increasing.but when i need to scroll to top ,it is not going,i need to scroll to specific position,

i have added the following :

```
                    mLiveChatList.setAdapter(adapter);
        mLiveChatList.requestLayout();
        mLiveChatList.setSelectionAfterHeaderView();
        mLiveChatList.setSelection(0);
        mLiveChatList.setSelection(mLiveChatList.getCount());
```

could anybody help me regarding this issue!! @Thanks

Comment: You might wanna get rid of *requestLayout()* and other *setSelection()* calls.  Have you tried ListView's **smoothScrollToPosition (int position)** method?  

You can check [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#smoothScrollToPosition(int))

Comment: @CanElmas yes..when i set selection as 0 it fixed at top only

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this:

```
ListView lv =(ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listsong);  
        lv.invalidateViews();
        lv.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

InvalidateViews is not necessary if you don't want the listview to rewrite its view